# PHP & PostgreSQL: how to display user-related data from database?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, postgresql

I have a login area which leads to my project, where the user can write calculations in a table. This table should save the input, so that only the logged in user sees his data. Now my question, how to do that? What has to be written in the execute? Is the foreach correct to put out the data?
I have a prepared statement:

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM calculations WHERE user_id = registered_users.user_id");
$sth->execute(array($_SESSION['user_id'], $date, $startkm, ...)); 
$calculations = $sth->fetchAll();
```

And my PHP-Code:

```
<?php foreach($calculations as $calculation) : ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $calculations->date ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $calculations->startkm ?></td>
                        ...
                    </tr>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </table>
```

Database:

```
CREATE TABLE calculations
(
  user_id INT NOT NULL REFERENCES registered_users (user_id),
  calc_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  date VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL, ...);
```

Comment: I am very sure this `SELECT * FROM calculations WHERE user_id = registered_users.user_id"` cannot work

Comment: no because i need parameters in the execute statement and I don´t know them.

Comment: you're supposed to pass some kind of `id` in that query. Post your database schema for more help

Comment: `CREATE TABLE calculations
(
  user_id INT NOT NULL REFERENCES registered_users (user_id),
  calc_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  date VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL, ...);`

Comment: post this in your question

Comment: ok, already did it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that `$_SESSION['user_id']` holds `user_id` of registered user.

```
<?php
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM calculations WHERE user_id = ?");
$sth->execute(array($_SESSION['user_id'])); 
$calculations = $sth->fetchAll();
?>
```